# extjs gridpanel not showing scrollbars

Tags: extjs, grid, scroll, extjs4

I am creating a page that only contains a gridpanel, I want my gridpanel to have scrollbars based on the browser size. To do this I am wrapping it in a viewport as discussed [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?45251-autoHeight-Grid-with-ScrollBar) and making sure I specify a layout as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817338/vertical-scrollbar-in-extjs-gridpanel). The grid renders fine but I am not getting any scroll bars. I've tried 'fit', 'border' and 'anchor' layouts but still no luck. The code looks like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    items: [{
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'fit',
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        store: myStore,
        loadMask: true,      
        columns: [{
            header: 'Account ID',
            dataIndex: 'acct_id',
            width: 70
        }, {
            header: 'First Name',
            dataIndex: 'first_name',
            width: 120
        }, {
            header: 'Last Name',
            dataIndex: 'last_name',
            width: 120
        }, {
            xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            header: 'Account Balance',
            dataIndex: 'acct_bal',
            width: 70,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney
        }, {
            xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            header: 'Credit',
            dataIndex: 'credit',
            width: 70,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney
        }, {
            xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            header: 'Debt',
            dataIndex: 'debt_bal',
            width: 70,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney
        }],
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set `fit` layout to `Viewport`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [...]
});
```

Setting layout in `GridPanel` have no effect.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. Obviously I missed something in the Sencha posts.